# Ordered array insert

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

Here is an exert from "Data Structures & Algorithms in Java" Second Edition by Robert Lafore. We are working with an ordered array attempting to insert an item in the array. I usually like to understand the lines while i code, but this seems to escape me. I understand what the first half is doing--searching for where to put the value in.

now the second part starting from for(int k=nElems; k>j; k--) is where i get stuck.
I think this is what its trying to say: set k equal to the size of the original array and decrements till its k is of size j. set array location k equal to k-1(or perhaps j-1?) then... then i get stuck in a[j] = value;.

Can someone please explain whats going on there? I thought arrays were immutable once created. One would think a brand new array is would be created.

```
public void insert(long value)    // put element into array
{
int j;

for(j=0; j<nElems; j++)         // find where it goes
if(a[j] > value) // (linear search)
    break;

for(int k=nElems; k>j; k--)     // move bigger ones up
    a[k] = a[k-1];
a[j] = value;                   // insert it
nElems++;                       // increment size
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int k=nElems
```

Start at the end.

```
k > j
```

While we haven't reached the target position...

```
a[k] = a[k-1];
```

Move the current element up one position to the right.

```
k--
```

And move to the left.

---

So, shift all elements between the target position and the end one position to the right.

> I thought arrays were immutable once created.

The array **size** is fixed once created - the element at any index can be modified or reassigned however you see fit.

What was probably done here - a larger array was created and `nElems` was used to indicate the number of populated values - the remaining indices would just be `null`. [Wikipedia's article on dynamic arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) briefly mentions this - the concept of *capacity* versus *size* - the capacity would be `a.length`, the size would be `nElems`. This is identical to how an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) works.

Comment: Thank You. Simply fell off my mind to consider the entire code. a "Max" array size was created previously. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's shifting the existent elements before inserting to make room for the new element

Comment: shifting "implies" that the size of an immutable array can be extended. I am simply trying to reason out the logic. I like to be able to tell it like a story.